# Using Green's function on the half-plane, verifying solution is harmonic and satisfies boundary condition

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, greens-function

> Use the Green's function for the half-plane to solve the problem
>   $$\begin{cases}
> \Delta u(x_1,x_2) = 0 \ \ \text{in the half-plane} \ x_2 > 0\\
> u(x_1,0) = g(x_1) \ \ \text{on the boundary} \ x_2 = 0
> \end{cases}$$
>   where the boundary condition is 
>   $$g(x_1) = \begin{cases}
> \pi \ \ \text{if} \ |x_1| \leq 1\\
> 0 \ \ \text{if} \ |x_1| > 1\\
> \end{cases}$$
>   Verify that the solution is, in fact, harmonic, and satisfies the given boundary condition.\
>   \noindent
>   Remark: In our theorems, we assumed that $g$ is continuous, which this one is not. What is happening at the two discontinuities?

Attempted (beginning) solution - The Green's function for the half-plane is given by
$$G(x,x_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\log |x - x_0| - \frac{1}{2\pi}\log |x - x^{*}_0|$$
where $x = x(x,y)$, $x_0 = (x_0,y_0)$, and $x^{*}_0 = (x_0,-y_0)$.

Now I am pretty confused with what to do next here, going through my professors notes I can seem to find anything related to Green's function in the half-plane. I had to search for it online to find it which is what is presented above.

The only part that seems remotely related in my notes is on the Half-space where we found the solution to Poisson's problem in the upper half place for $2$ dimensions which is 
$$u(x_1,x_2) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\log \frac{(y_1 - y_2)^2 + (y_2 - x_2)^2}{(y_1 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 + x_2)^2}f(y_1,y_2)dy_2 dy_1 + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x_2}{(y_1 - x_1)^2 + x_2^{2}}g(y_1)dy_1$$

My apologies ahead of time if this question is a bit messy. I just don't understand what I need to do here. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Attempted solution (sort of) -  The Green's function for the half-plane is given by
$$G(x,x_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\log |x - x_0| - \frac{1}{2\pi}\log |x - x^{*}_0|$$
where $x = x(x,y)$, $x_0 = (x_0,y_0)$, and $x^{*}_0 = (x_0,-y_0)$. In our case we have $$G(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x_1 - x_2| - \frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x_1 - \tilde{x_2}|$$
Thus 
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial n} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{x_1 - \tilde{x_2}}{|\tilde{x_2} - x_1|^2}\right)\Bigg|_{\tilde{x_2} = 0} = \frac{1}{2\pi x_1}$$
Thus we have $$u(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x_1}g(x_1)dx_1$$
Not sure if this is correct, any suggestions or comments are appreciated. If it is correct, is it possible to evaluate further? How do I show that the solution is harmonic?

Attempted solution 3 - The Green's function for the half-plane is given by
$$G(x,x_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\log |x - x_0| - \frac{1}{2\pi}\log |x - x^{*}_0|$$
where $x = x(x,y)$, $x_0 = (x_0,y_0)$, and $x^{*}_0 = (x_0,-y_0)$. In our case we have
\begin{align*}
G &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\log\left(\sqrt{(\tilde{x_1} - x_1)^2}\right) - \frac{1}{2\pi}\log\left(\sqrt{(\tilde{x_1}-x_1)^2 + (\tilde{x_2} + x_2)^2}\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi}\left[\log\left((\tilde{x_1} - x_1)^2 + (\tilde{x_2} - x_2)^2\right) - \log\left((\tilde{x_1} - x_1)^2 + (\tilde{x_2} + x_2)^2\right)\right]
\end{align*}
Now,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial n}\Bigg|_{\tilde{x_2} = 0} &= -\frac{1}{4\pi}\left[\frac{2(\tilde{x_2} - x_2)}{(\tilde{x_1} - x_1)^2 + (\tilde{x_2} - x_2)^2} - \frac{2(\tilde{x_2} + x_2)}{(\tilde{x_1} - x_1)^2 + (\tilde{x_2} + x_2)^2} \right]\Bigg|_{\tilde{x_2} = 0}\\
&= \frac{x_2}{\pi((\tilde{x_1} - x_1)^2 + x_2^{2})}
\end{align*}
Thus we have 
$$u(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x_2}{(\tilde{x_1} - x_1)^2 + x_2^{2}}g(x_1)dx_1$$
We see that $\Delta u(x_1,x_2) = 0$ since $g(x_1)$ is a constant function and taking the derivative with respect to $x_1$ will equal $0$. Therefore the solution $u(x_1,x_2)$ is harmonic.

I am not sure if this is correct or not. Also, how do we show that this solution satisfies the boundary condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Using Green's Second Identity with $\nabla'^2 G(x_1,x_2|x_1',x_2')=-\delta(x_1-x_1')\delta(x_2-x_2')$ in distribution to write

$$\begin{align}
u(x_1,x_2)&=\int_{x_2\ge 0}\left(G(x_1,x_2|x_1',x_2')\underbrace{\nabla'^2 u(x_1',x_2')}_{=0}-u(x_1',x_2')\underbrace{\nabla'^2 G(x_1,x_2|x_1',x_2')}_{=-\delta(x_1-x_1')\delta(x_2-x_2')}\right)\,dx_1'\,dx_2'\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left.\left(\underbrace{G(x_1,x_2|x_1',x_2')}_{=0\,\text{at}\,x_2'=0}\frac{\partial u(x_1',x_2')}{\partial x_2'}-\underbrace{u(x_1',x_2')}_{=g(x_1')\,\text{at}\,x_2'=0}\frac{\partial G(x_1,x_2|x_1',x_2')}{\partial x_2'}\right)\right|_{x_2'=0}\,dx_1'\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x_1')\left.\left(\frac{\partial G(x_1,x_2|x_1',x_2')}{\partial x_2'}\right)\right|_{x_2'=0}\,dx_1
\end{align}$$

Comment: I am not sure if I follow from my book: Partial Differential Equations by Walter A. Strauss, Green's second identity is given by $$\iiint_{D}(u\Delta v - v\Delta u)dx = \iint_{\partial D}\left(u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n} - v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\right)dS$$

Comment: I probably just don't understand the formula or how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: You have the correct formula for $\mathbb{R}^3$ if $v=G$; for $\mathbb{R}^2$ reduce the 3-D integral over $D$ to a 2-D integral over the upper-half plane and the integral over $\partial D$ to a contour integral that is comprised of the real line and a semicircle of  "infinite radius." The integral over the "infinite semicircle" is $0$ given the behavior of $G$.   The left-hand side of the one you wrote becomes $u(x_1,x_2)$.  The right-hand side becomes $- \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x_1')\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_2'}\,dx_1'$ as expected.

Comment: My apologies, my intellectual inferiority does not comprehend. I should have mentioned the formula is for $\mathbb{R}^3$. But I just don't understand how we use it for this particular problem it just doesn't make sense to me on where I begin given what I have.

Comment: The solution I posted is all you need.  It gives you the answer.  Just use the form of $G$ you wrote in your OP, take its derivative with respect to $x_2'$, then after that let $x_2'=0$.  You will get an integral representation for $u$

Comment: I know, but I just want to understand how to do it myself and I am just not seeing it...

Comment: For example, we have $$G(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x_1 - x_2| - \frac{1}{2\pi}|x_1 - x_2^{*}|$$ then $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial n} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{x_1 - x_2^{*}}{|x_2^{*} - x_1|^2}\right)$$ Then for $x_2^{*} = 0$ we have $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial n} = \frac{1}{2\pi x_1}$$ Not sure if that is right but yea If it isn't then I am completely lost

Comment: It's not correct.  The notation should be $$G=\frac1{2\pi}\log\left(\sqrt{(x_1-x_1')^2+(x_2-x_2')^2}\right)-\frac1{2\pi}\log\left(\sqrt{(x_1-x_1')^2+(x_2+x_2')^2}\right)$$Now take $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_2'}$

Comment: How did you get that formula?

Comment: That is the Green (or Green's) function that satisfies $\nabla^2 G=-\delta(x_1-x_1')\delta(x_2-x_2')$ and $G(x_1,x_2;x_1',x_2'=0)=0$.

Comment: Ok thank you for the comments, I will update my solution later this afternoon. Once I do so, I will have the solution in integral form. What is the next step in showing that it is harmonic?

Comment: Take the Laplacian of that integral expression and verify that it is $0$.

Comment: Is there a way of getting rid of the sqrt to make the derivative less complicated

Comment: Yes.  $\log(x^a)=a\log(x)$.

Comment: so could I write $$G = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\left[\log\left((x_1 - \tilde{x_1})^2 + (x_2 - \tilde{x_2})^2\right) - \log\left((x_1 - \tilde{x_1})^2 + (x_2 + \tilde{x_2})^2\right)\right]$$

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62547/discussion-between-mark-viola-and-wolfgang-1).

Comment: I re-posted another attempted solution if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: I am in the chat, whenever you are ready

Comment: Hey Mark, could you take a look at my new solution so I can be done with this problem?

Comment: If you replace $g(x_1)$ with $g(\tilde{x_1})$ and $dx_1$ with $d\tilde{x_1}$, it looks like you might be finished.  But I have not gone through the details.  And use what you are given about $g$ too.  Then, the integral goes from $-1$ to $1$, $g$ is constant there, and you can integrate in closed form.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the comment

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Hey Mark, I saw your linkedIn and I have to say your quite impressive. I am actually a PhD student but I thought of getting some experience before I continue another 3 years. I was wondering if I could connect with you on LinedIn?

Comment: Sorry Mark, second question do we evaluate the integral as $$u(x_1,x_2) = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x_2}{(\tilde{x_1} - x_1)^2 + x_2^{2}}\pi d\tilde{x_1}$$ Also how do we show that the solution satisfies the boundary condition?

Comment: You may invite me to "LinkIn" and you can evaluate that integral in closed form.

Comment: Hey Mark, I understand it can be evaluated in closed-form, with the integral I wrote above, did I set that up correctly?

Comment: I believe that your integral is correct (except for the factor of $\pi$).

Comment: I see, but I thought $g(x_1) = \pi$ for the domain we are integrating

Comment: Hey, Mark how do we show the solution satisfies the boundary condition?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 Take the limit of the resulting integral expression as $x_2\to 0$.

Comment: Ok, so we will have $$\lim_{x_2\to 0}\left(tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x_1}{x_2}\right) - tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-1-x_1}{x_2}\right)\right)$$ and we get something out of that I suppose, why does that show us that the solution satisfies the boundary condition?